# Redirecting the URL from One Server to another after Filtering in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I need help regarding routing the spring Controller from one server to another server if and only if the controller handler is not available in first server.

*Example:*  I have a server with name `www.example1.com` in that i will maintain a predefined list of controllers to be handled. If the request came from client  like `www.example1.com/user/add`. Now in the URL, controller is `/user/add` . If the controller is available in the list of controllers in example1 server, then first server will be handled. Otherwise it should be redirected to other server like  `www.example2.com/user/add`  .

I searched but not able to get the solution.

Comment: I dont understand very well your question. Are you asking about go to diferents servers that it depends of your request? In that case you can use an interceptor

Comment: The request should go from first server. I will redirect the request by adding access token for the request to the second server, if the handling controller is not available in the list of controllers I have in the first server.

Comment: are you talking about load balancer? and why are you maintaining different requests in different servers?? and are you sure second server contains request mapping if not the first?

Comment: @prasanna Kumar second server surely will have the controllers if it was not there in first server. Iam not talking about load balancing. Suppose 10 different applications are there with some X module is in common. Iam creating a server which will handle only X module for all applications.. All the requests to the all other applications should go through my server only. My server will act as intermediate server and will add some auth token and should forward to the other server.The second server will accept the request if the auth token which is in the request is valid